# Cloud trail event logging S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, terraform, amazon-cloudtrail

I want to log the events when I download any file from download folder, if I download file from any other folder say upload then it should not log that event.

I'm using the below code in cloud shell:

```
aws cloudtrail put-event-selectors --trail-name name \
--advanced-event-selectors \
'[
    {
            "Name": "S3EventSelector",
            "FieldSelectors": [
                { "Field": "eventCategory", "Equals": ["Data"] },
                { "Field": "resources.type", "Equals": ["AWS::S3::Object"] },
                {"Field": "eventName", "Equals":["GetObject"]},          
                { "Field": "resources.ARN", "StartsWith": ["arn:aws:s3:::bucket/"] }
            ]
        }
]'
```

Here, I'm getting the logs from every folder if I download any file.

Comment: try "StartsWith": ["arn:aws:s3:::bucket/folder-you-want-to-log"]

Comment: I cannot do this since I have multiple folders and all of them can have download folder.

Comment: I don't know if wildcard works in this case, but maybe try "arn:aws:s3:::bucket/*/download" ?

Comment: Wildcard didn't help, it logged every event. Can you please help me with another way?

Comment: How come wildcard logged every event? "arn:aws:s3:::bucket/*/download/*" works then event with `arn:aws:s3:::bucket/*/other-folder/*` should not trigger. Please test again.

Comment: Actually it didn't log any event when I used "arn:aws:s3:::bucket/*/download/*" my folder pattern is something like: folder/download/filename, folder/upload/filename

Comment: `StartsWith` can be array so if wildcard doesn't work, you might need to add all the value to it